# 3d Unity C# enemy walks through walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, move, clip

Hello wizards of the internet,

I'm making a 3D first person RPG where you can attack enemies which are located around the map. My current script is working fine, however there is one problem: the enemies are walking through walls whenever they are focused on the player.

I've already tried a few things to fix this, but unfortunately there was no result. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**goblinAttack.cs:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class goblinAttack : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    static Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(direction,this.transform.forward);
        if(Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) < 10 && angle < 30)
        {

            direction.y = 0;

            this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation,
                                        Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f);

            anim.SetBool("isIdle",false);
            if(direction.magnitude > 5)
            {
                this.transform.Translate(0,0,0.10f);
                anim.SetBool("isRunning",true);
                anim.SetBool("isAttacking",false);
                anim.SetBool("isCrying",true);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetBool("isAttacking",true);
                anim.SetBool("isRunning",false);
                anim.SetBool("isCrying",false);
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
            anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
            anim.SetBool("isCrying",false);

        }

    }
}
```

**NPC settings:**

[image: settings]

Comment: Do you have a mesh collider on your wall objects?

Comment: You're going to need to perform some pathfinding to find the legal path to the player. Otherwise, the goblin will try running directly at the player, which will mean either being stopped by or running through potentially easily circumventable obstacles in the way.

Comment: Yes, I do. But it still moves through the wall.

Answer (score 1):

A rigidbody marked with IsKinematic [is not affected by Forces, collisions or joints.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) Keep in mind that using Transform.Translate() with a rigidbody might result in bugs, too - consider [Rigidbody.MovePosition()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) which is intended for use with physics. Overall however, I'd suggest you use [pathfinding](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html) to make sure that the enemy doesn't attempt to walk through walls in the first place.

Comment: Has nothing to do with IsKinematic. This is a Transform.Translate issue. MovePosition or AddForce should be used.

Comment: I see. What exactly do I need to change to MovePosition though? All transforms?

Comment: You need to get the Rigidbody with `GetComponent`  then replace `this.transform.Translate(0,0,0.10f);` with `yourRigidBody.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: Hmm, apparently it still walks through the wall but with slower speed. Could it be the wall then?